# what race would potetially have a telekenetic ability?

Tags: magic, fantasy-races

I'm creating a roleplay character and really want it to be a female with telekenesis. But what race would fit having that ability? I thought maybe witch, but are there any other races that might be able to manipulate the movement of objects etc through hand gestures, thought.

Comment: Any race you want. It's your world, your rules. Like with anything magic based.

Comment: Witches are a "race"? Wouldn't such a designation stretch the meaning of the word "race" way past the breaking point?